# Auto deletion from memory after indexing with solr

Tags: solr, solrj

because of lack memory i want to force solr to write the index into hard space and does not keep the file opened in memory,How can i do that in solrj?
i add the solr.commit() after each document indexed but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Few pointers :-

To immediately commit data use -

```
req.setAction( UpdateRequest.ACTION.COMMIT, false, false );
```

or

```
solr.commit(false, false)
```

The arguments are waitFlush and waitSearcher which are true by default and needs to be set to false.

Also revisit the configurations for maxBufferedDocs & ramBufferSizeMB in solrconfig.xml